# Processing large csv file on AWS s3 with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku, amazon-s3

I am deploying my application from a development site to heroku and didn't realize that Heroku doesn't allow you the ability to save uploaded files.  I am now in the process of trying to switch the file structure over to s3.

The application accepts csv files that are processed and added to the database.  Some of the csv files are very large (over 100k rows/13megs).  I was initially using a rake task to process the file by reading each line and saving it to the database.

Now that I have to use AWS s3, I am not sure how I can download such a large file and process it since Heroku may delete the file while its still being processed?  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to process large file with heroku?

Thank you!

Comment: While a dyno is running its filesystem won't be wiped (there may be a limit, but you're certainly fine with 10s of mb of temp files). It's perfectly OK to download a file from s3 to /tmp, work on it, and put the results into your database.

Comment: Thank you for the response Spike